# Malformed dns response

Tags: c, sockets, dns

I'm trying to send a dns response message to my browser, now I created some structs and filled one in for the website of drupal.org.

When I'm sending the response wiresharks sais it is malformed,
could someone take a look?

```
dnsresponse response;
    unsigned char buf[sizeof response];


    response.id = (unsigned short) htons(GetCurrentProcessId());
    response.response = 1;
    response.opCode = 0;
    response.authoritative = 0;
    response.truncated = 0;
    response.recursion = 1;
    response.recursionAvField = 1;
    response.z = 0;

    response.replyCode = 0;

    response.questions = 1;
    response.answer = 1;
    response.authorityRRS = 0;
    response.additionalRRS = 0;

    response.qName = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof("www.drupal.org"));
    response.qType = 1;
    response.qClass = 1;

    response.aName = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof("www.drupal.org"));
    response.aType = 1;
    response.aClass = 1;
    response.ttl = 0;
    response.dataLength = 9;
    response.addr = 2362640912;

    memcpy(buf, &response, sizeof response);
```

My struct is as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
unsigned short id; // ID nummer
unsigned short response :1; // 1 is reply 0 is query
unsigned short opCode :4;
unsigned short authoritative :1; // DNS server is authoritative server
unsigned short truncated :1;
unsigned short recursion :1; // Recursie of niet
unsigned short recursionAvField :1; // Recursie in reply
unsigned short z :3;
//unsigned short aa;
//unsigned short nAD;
unsigned short replyCode :4;

unsigned short questions;
unsigned short answer;
unsigned short authorityRRS;
unsigned short additionalRRS;

unsigned char * qName;
unsigned short qType;
unsigned short qClass;

unsigned char * aName;
unsigned short aType;
unsigned short aClass;
int ttl :32;
unsigned short dataLength;
unsigned int addr :32;
}dnsresponse;
```

Kind regards,

Comment: You need to read the RFC documents for DNS. Encoding a DNS message is not that trivial. (Though, in particular, you have malloced pointers, it doesn't make sense to send pointer values out in a packet, pointers are only relevant in your own program)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know dns at the protocol level, but your problem is that

```
malloc(sizeof("string"))
```

does **not** duplicate a string, it only reserves space for the bytes needed to do it -- hint: strdup

EDIT: d'oh, I only read the "get the dns spec" part of nos's comment. Sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fundamentally flawed. You cannot express a DNS packet with a struct, because the strings in a DNS packet are variable length, i.e. fields following a string will be at different offsets in the packet depending on the length of the preceding strings.

Your struct has char-pointers in place of each string, and each pointer is typically a 32-bit value that points to some other place in memory. Therefore when you try to send the struct as represented in memory, you will be sending more or less random 32-bit values in place of the strings.

Here is a fairly illustrative guide to what the DNS packets should look like: 
http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DNSMessageProcessingandGeneralMessageFormat.htm